# Personal phones used for company business

Tags: termination, phone

If I used my personal cell phone to conduct business for my employer and they pay partial for the bill can they keep my phone upon termination?

Comment: Do you mean your phone number or the handset?

Comment: Who bought the phone? Under who's name is the contract with the phone company?

Comment: Welcome to [BYOD policies and procedures.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=BYOD+policies+and+procedures). The company likely cannot keep your phone *if* it is your property. However, the company's policies and procedures probably say something like you have to surrender it for a wipe upon separation or termination. (I helped two US banks setup their mobile security practices. These are typical policies that are present. In some instances we had technical controls to enforce it, like remote wipe through iPhoneConfigurator).

Comment: Also see discussions like [Legal and technical BYOD pitfalls highlighted at RSA security conference](https://bringyourownit.com/2012/10/16/legal-and-technical-byod-pitfalls-highlighted-at-rsa-conference/).

Comment: @jww so you wipe personal contact info from a personal device? Can you do that under the various data protection acts? Does that contract supercede those acts? And will a backup & restore be useful...

Comment: @SolarMike - So those are some of the thorny points with BYOD. The RSA security conference presentation (and similar articles) discuss some of the potential legal issues, like blowing away non-company data along with company data. As far as I know, no case has been adjudicated in the US. (It also depends on the implementation. For example, if company data is in a secure container through an app, then it may be possible to blow away the app's data rather than wipe the whole device).

Comment: @jww I did not ask for articles, the EU has laws about personal data, where it is stored and how it is used. Does the US?

Comment: @SolarMike - Sorry, my experience is in the US. I don't know how mobile security policies and procedures intersect with the EU's GDPR. The US does not have a GDPR equivalent, and corporate america is mostly free to do what it wants. As far as I know there is no case law in the US establishing the boundaries with respect to mobile security policies. At the moment the best we have are the opinions of legal professionals put forth in presentations like the one from [RSA security conference](https://bringyourownit.com/2012/10/16/legal-and-technical-byod-pitfalls-highlighted-at-rsa-conference/).

Comment: @jww and some companies that fight for personal data security...

Answer (score 5):

> If I used my personal cell phone to conduct business for my employer and they pay partial for the bill can they keep my phone upon termination?

If you want to know the legal aspects perhaps it would be better if you consult a lawyer (and mention your location as well).

Now, in practical terms seems to me that they can't or shouldn't.

You say you use your personal phone (which you bought I take it), and that the company pays part of the bills. Seems to me that they are doing the right thing by recognizing that part of your job entails making phone calls and paying you for that as compensation... but the phone is yours. *At most they should stop paying part of your bills when you are terminated.*

Different case would be if *they* gave you the phone, and they payed for it. In that case the phone would be company property and should be given back when terminated or leaving.

Comment: And they don't own your contact list either... They are probably paying a token amount towards the connection charges... Asking for your contacts is private information sisters, brothers friends etc...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's *your* phone and your contract does not state anything else, then

## No

they cannot. How would that work out? I regularly use my private car for company trips and get reimbursed for that. Doesn't mean the company gets to keep my car when I leave. Anybody suggesting that would be considered out of their mind.

Comment: +1. If they want to control the phone, it needs to be their property.

Answer (score 0):

If it's your phone, meaning you purchased it and your name is on the purchase contract then no, they can't keep your phone. That would be analogous to them keeping your vehicle if they paid you for the business use of your vehicle.

Comment: Or they can keep your house if you worked from home at any point. What is a purchase contract?